# How to format ref name for section with cleverref?

Tags: xetex, cleveref

Say I have a section 1.11 and I want to format its ref name as: Chapter 1 Section 11.
I have tried the following:

```
\creflabelformat{section}{#2 Chapter #1 #3}%
```

and it yields Chapter 1.11.

What should I do to split "1.11" into two parts?

My minimal example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\creflabelformat{section}{#2#1#3} % How should I fix this?

\begin{document}
\section{A}
\label{sec:A}
\subsection{A1}
\subsection{A2}
\section{B}
\cref{sec:A}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Let me make sure I understand your formatting objective: the "full" section number is formatted as `x.y`, and you want to create a cross-reference formatted as `Chapter x Section y`. Please advise if this interpretation is correct.

Comment: @Mico Yes. I've tried to split `x.y` with *xparse* package, but it didn't work.